# Unable to show form using controller (module)

Tags: views, theming, forms, 8

I want to make custom page in drupal with form, I checked few examples showing page in drupal via module and example of form via module, i tried to merge them but no success.
I made a custom page using drupal module with template (twig) file.

Below is my controller code

```
namespace Drupal\booktestdrive\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class BiveController extends ControllerBase {
  public function show() {
    $form_class = '\Drupal\booktestdrive\Form\TestForm';
    return [
        '#theme' => 'bive_page_theme',
        '#form' => \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form_class),
    ];
  }
}
```

Template file code

**bive_page_theme.html.twig**

```
<section> hii
{{ form }}

</section>
```

**i also created form at src/form/BiveForm.php**

```
namespace Drupal\bive\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class BiveForm extends FormBase {
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'booktestdrive_form';
  }
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['first_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('First Name*')),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['last_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('Last Name')),
      '#required' => FALSE,
    );

    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
    );
    return $form;
  }

    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

      if (strlen($form_state->getValue('candidate_number')) < 10) {
        $form_state->setErrorByName('candidate_number', $this->t('Mobile number is too short.'));
      }

    }


  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

   // drupal_set_message($this->t('@can_name ,Your application is being submitted!', array('@can_name' => $form_state->getValue('candidate_name'))));

    foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
      drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value);
    }

   }
}
```

**Routing.yml**

```
bdrive.book:
  path: '/brive'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\brive\Controller\BriveController::book'
    _title: 'Test'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

brive.form:
 path: '/brive-form'
 defaults:
   _title: 'Application form'
   _form: '\Drupal\booktestdrive\Form\BriveForm'
 requirements:
   _permission: 'access content'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need define new function theme **bive_page_theme** before call it. You can see [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x) and [example](https://www.drupal.org/node/2640110). In your case, you can write more code in file **.module**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function Your_Module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return [
        'bive_page_theme' => [
            'variables' => [
              'form' => NULL,
            ],
            'path' => $path . '/templates',
        ]
    ];
}
```

and create file **bive_page_theme.html.twig** in folder **templates** of module. Clear cache and go to page.

Comment: hey i am already created page with module i want to show custom form on my page

Comment: What's code in file routing.yml of you?

Answer (score 0):

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer;
//Here declare your class
class TestController extends ControllerBase {
protected $renderer;
public function __construct(Renderer $renderer) {
        $this->renderer = $renderer;
    }

```
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
        $container->get('renderer')
    );
```

public function content() { 
      $markup = $this->renderer->render(\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\questions\Form\QuestionForm'));

```
   return [
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => $markup,
];
```

}
}
in your controller you can do like this also